# Constant BSOD caused by SynTP.sys, NEED HELP BADLY

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod, crash, touchpad

I'm currently using an HP 15-BA009DX laptop running Windows 10 version 2004, version 10.0.19041.1466.

Everything was functioning properly until yesterday when I noticed that my system initiated an upgrade to version 22H2. Unfortunately, during the upgrade process, I accidentally restarted my laptop. As a result, I encountered a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) with an error caused by SynTP.sys. The specific stop code displayed was `PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA.`

I took several steps to resolve the problem.

- First, I created a bootable USB and accessed the Windows Recovery Environment (RE).
- From there, I attempted various command prompts and even tried entering safe mode.

However, regardless of the method I used, my laptop continued to reboot into the BSOD caused by the touchpad driver.

It's worth noting that I don't actively use the touchpad driver, and I even disconnected the ribbon cable to disable it physically. However, I neglected to uninstall the driver software before removing the cable. In an effort to rectify the situation, I manually deleted the affected driver through the command prompt.

Unfortunately, even after taking this action, the BSOD issue persists. At this point, my primary concern is preserving my personal files. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this problem without losing any of my data.

Diskpart partitions:

[image: Diskpart partitions]

Diskpart volumes:

[image: Diskpart volumes]

SSD in `diskmgmt`:

[image: SSD in diskmgmt]

[bcdedit file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jga5jzg7db9qv2h/Firmware%20Boot%20Manager.txt?dl=0), [SrtTrail.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jar4ufn0a980yeu/SrtTrail.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Are you able to put your drive in a carrier and recover the files on a working machine?

Comment: I can recover my files, but I need to recover some from my recycle bin. Access is denied if I try to open them. My SSD is fine in terms of contents, but something got messed up with my boot and I'm super stressed out rn.

Comment: First make a full disk image, so you can try recovering the recycle Bin later. Then download the Windows ISO from MS and reinstall, keeping files. No guarantee the recycle bin will still have files, though.

Comment: I was wondering if you could look at the images I provided, is everything looking good so far? Also, lmk what other pics I should Include.

Comment: You can’t “reinstall” Windows resulting in a state where deleted files in the recycle bin can be recovered if you can’t boot into Windows to perform the in-place reinstall

Comment: I need to recover some from my recycle bin.  ......... People insist on using Recycle Bin for permanent storage. Do not do this.  Very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the recover enviroment

```
dism /image:C: /Remove-Driver /driver:some.inf
```

Now the problem is windows often renames the inf file from whatever.inf to oem1234.inf

Maybe you could use this to help identify the correct INF name.

```
Dism /Image:C:\ /Get-Drivers /format:table
```

[image]

Locate the published file name for the "original file name" of SynTP.sys